# WPF MaterialDesign app, When trying to publish working application I get error "The target "StaticWebAssetsPrepareForRun" does not exist in project"

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I'm building a WPF application using Material Design Toolkit as a basis. Everything works well when I run the app inside Visual Studio but when I'm trying to publish it I get.

> "The target "StaticWebAssetsPrepareForRun" does not exist in project"

It also references besides the error the **Microsoft.CSharp.Core.Targets** in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets

From what I read so far people say it's related to Blazor Application which I don't have anything to do with functionalities of that platform.

I don't use any "StaticWebAssets" and I can't find where in my code it references to it. The simplest way to solve it from my understanding is to remove the code where the program tries to reach it but where is that..

I checked my NuGet Manager and tried to locate if there was a package I could install that would solve the issue by making StaticWebAssets available but not use it.

Here is my **App.Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MaterialDesign3Demo.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
             If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
             requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization. 
            Remove this element if your application requires this virtualization for backwards
            compatibility.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on and is
           is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements and Windows will 
           automatically selected the most compatible environment. -->

      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />

      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />

      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher
       DPIs. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications are automatically DPI-aware and do not need 
       to opt in. Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Framework 4.6 that opt into this setting, should 
       also set the 'EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing' setting to 'true' in their app.config. -->
  
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <!-- The combination of below two tags have the following effect : 
      1) Per-Monitor for >= RS1 (Windows 10 Anniversary Update)
      2) System < RS1 -->
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor, System</dpiAwareness>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>

  
  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!--
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  -->

</assembly>
```

Here is my **Microsoft.CSharp.Core.Targets**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements. The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license. See the LICENSE file in the project root for more information. -->
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- .NETCoreApp < 3.0, .NETStandard < 2.1, or any other target framework -->
    <_MaxSupportedLangVersion Condition="('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' != '.NETCoreApp' OR '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' &lt; '3.0') AND
                                         ('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' != '.NETStandard' OR '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' &lt; '2.1')">7.3</_MaxSupportedLangVersion>

    <!-- .NETCoreApp < 5.0, .NETStandard == 2.1 -->
    <_MaxSupportedLangVersion Condition="(('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' AND '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' &lt; '5.0') OR
                                          ('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETStandard' AND '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' == '2.1')) AND
                                          '$(_MaxSupportedLangVersion)' == ''">8.0</_MaxSupportedLangVersion>

    <!-- .NETCoreApp == 5.0 -->
    <_MaxSupportedLangVersion Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' AND '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' == '5.0' AND
                                         '$(_MaxSupportedLangVersion)' == ''">9.0</_MaxSupportedLangVersion>

    <!-- .NETCoreApp == 6.0 -->
    <_MaxSupportedLangVersion Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' AND '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' == '6.0' AND
                                         '$(_MaxSupportedLangVersion)' == ''">10.0</_MaxSupportedLangVersion>

    <!-- .NETCoreApp == 7.0 -->
    <_MaxSupportedLangVersion Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' AND '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' == '7.0' AND
                                         '$(_MaxSupportedLangVersion)' == ''">11.0</_MaxSupportedLangVersion>

    <MaxSupportedLangVersion>$(_MaxSupportedLangVersion)</MaxSupportedLangVersion>
    <LangVersion Condition="'$(LangVersion)' == '' AND '$(_MaxSupportedLangVersion)' != ''">$(_MaxSupportedLangVersion)</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CoreCompile"
          Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);
                  @(Compile);
                  @(_CoreCompileResourceInputs);
                  $(ApplicationIcon);
                  $(KeyOriginatorFile);
                  @(ReferencePathWithRefAssemblies);
                  @(CompiledLicenseFile);
                  @(LinkResource);
                  @(EmbeddedDocumentation);
                  $(Win32Resource);
                  $(Win32Manifest);
                  @(CustomAdditionalCompileInputs);
                  $(ResolvedCodeAnalysisRuleSet);
                  @(AdditionalFiles);
                  @(EmbeddedFiles);
                  @(Analyzer);
                  @(EditorConfigFiles);
                  $(StaticWebAssetsPrepareForRun)"

          Outputs="@(DocFileItem);
                   @(IntermediateAssembly);
                   @(IntermediateRefAssembly);
                   @(_DebugSymbolsIntermediatePath);
                   $(NonExistentFile);
                   @(CustomAdditionalCompileOutputs)"
          Returns="@(CscCommandLineArgs)"
          DependsOnTargets="$(CoreCompileDependsOn);_BeforeVBCSCoreCompile">
    <!-- These two compiler warnings are raised when a reference is bound to a different version
             than specified in the assembly reference version number.  MSBuild raises the same warning in this case,
             so the compiler warning would be redundant. -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' != 'v1.0') and ('$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' != 'v1.1')">
      <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1701;1702</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- To match historical behavior, when inside VS11+ disable the warning from csc.exe indicating that no sources were passed in-->
      <NoWarn Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' AND '$(VisualStudioVersion)' != '' AND '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &gt; '10.0'">$(NoWarn);2008</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- If the user has specified AppConfigForCompiler, we'll use it. If they have not, but they set UseAppConfigForCompiler,
                 then we'll use AppConfig -->
      <AppConfigForCompiler Condition="'$(AppConfigForCompiler)' == '' AND '$(UseAppConfigForCompiler)' == 'true'">$(AppConfig)</AppConfigForCompiler>

      <!-- If we are targeting winmdobj we want to specifically the pdbFile property since we do not want it to collide with the output of winmdexp-->
      <PdbFile Condition="'$(PdbFile)' == '' AND '$(OutputType)' == 'winmdobj' AND '$(_DebugSymbolsProduced)' == 'true'">$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetName).compile.pdb</PdbFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Condition is to filter out the _CoreCompileResourceInputs so that it doesn't pass in culture resources to the compiler -->
    <Csc Condition="'%(_CoreCompileResourceInputs.WithCulture)' != 'true'"
         AdditionalLibPaths="$(AdditionalLibPaths)"
         AddModules="@(AddModules)"
         AdditionalFiles="@(AdditionalFiles)"
         AllowUnsafeBlocks="$(AllowUnsafeBlocks)"
         AnalyzerConfigFiles="@(EditorConfigFiles)"
         Analyzers="@(Analyzer)"
         ApplicationConfiguration="$(AppConfigForCompiler)"
         BaseAddress="$(BaseAddress)"
         CheckForOverflowUnderflow="$(CheckForOverflowUnderflow)"
         ChecksumAlgorithm="$(ChecksumAlgorithm)"
         CodeAnalysisRuleSet="$(ResolvedCodeAnalysisRuleSet)"
         CodePage="$(CodePage)"
         DebugType="$(DebugType)"
         DefineConstants="$(DefineConstants)"
         DelaySign="$(DelaySign)"
         DisabledWarnings="$(NoWarn)"
         DisableSdkPath="$(DisableSdkPath)"
         DocumentationFile="@(DocFileItem)"
         EmbedAllSources="$(EmbedAllSources)"
         EmbeddedFiles="@(EmbeddedFiles)"
         EmitDebugInformation="$(DebugSymbols)"
         EnvironmentVariables="$(CscEnvironment)"
         ErrorEndLocation="$(ErrorEndLocation)"
         ErrorLog="$(ErrorLog)"
         ErrorReport="$(ErrorReport)"
         Features="$(Features)"
         FileAlignment="$(FileAlignment)"
         GeneratedFilesOutputPath="$(CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath)"
         GenerateFullPaths="$(GenerateFullPaths)"
         HighEntropyVA="$(HighEntropyVA)"
         Instrument="$(Instrument)"
         KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)"
         KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)"
         LangVersion="$(LangVersion)"
         LinkResources="@(LinkResource)"
         MainEntryPoint="$(StartupObject)"
         ModuleAssemblyName="$(ModuleAssemblyName)"
         NoConfig="true"
         NoLogo="$(NoLogo)"
         NoStandardLib="$(NoCompilerStandardLib)"
         NoWin32Manifest="$(NoWin32Manifest)"
         Nullable="$(Nullable)"
         Optimize="$(Optimize)"
         Deterministic="$(Deterministic)"
         PublicSign="$(PublicSign)"
         OutputAssembly="@(IntermediateAssembly)"
         OutputRefAssembly="@(IntermediateRefAssembly)"
         PdbFile="$(PdbFile)"
         Platform="$(PlatformTarget)"
         Prefer32Bit="$(Prefer32Bit)"
         PreferredUILang="$(PreferredUILang)"
         ProvideCommandLineArgs="$(ProvideCommandLineArgs)"
         References="@(ReferencePathWithRefAssemblies)"
         RefOnly="$(ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly)"
         ReportAnalyzer="$(ReportAnalyzer)"
         ReportIVTs="$(ReportIVTs)"
         Resources="@(_CoreCompileResourceInputs);@(CompiledLicenseFile)"
         ResponseFiles="$(CompilerResponseFile)"
         RuntimeMetadataVersion="$(RuntimeMetadataVersion)"
         SharedCompilationId="$(SharedCompilationId)"
         SkipAnalyzers="$(_SkipAnalyzers)"
         SkipCompilerExecution="$(SkipCompilerExecution)"
         Sources="@(Compile)"
         SubsystemVersion="$(SubsystemVersion)"
         TargetType="$(OutputType)"
         ToolExe="$(CscToolExe)"
         ToolPath="$(CscToolPath)"
         TreatWarningsAsErrors="$(TreatWarningsAsErrors)"
         UseHostCompilerIfAvailable="$(UseHostCompilerIfAvailable)"
         UseSharedCompilation="$(UseSharedCompilation)"
         Utf8Output="$(Utf8Output)"
         VsSessionGuid="$(VsSessionGuid)"
         WarningLevel="$(WarningLevel)"
         WarningsAsErrors="$(WarningsAsErrors)"
         WarningsNotAsErrors="$(WarningsNotAsErrors)"
         Win32Icon="$(ApplicationIcon)"
         Win32Manifest="$(Win32Manifest)"
         Win32Resource="$(Win32Resource)"
         PathMap="$(PathMap)"
         SourceLink="$(SourceLink)">
      <Output TaskParameter="CommandLineArgs" ItemName="CscCommandLineArgs" />
    </Csc>

    <ItemGroup>
      <_CoreCompileResourceInputs Remove="@(_CoreCompileResourceInputs)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <CallTarget Targets="$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)" Condition="'$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)' != ''" />
  </Target>

  <!-- When we load a project in Visual Studio, the project system first does an evaluation pass of the
       project, and hands the resulting list of <Compile> items to the language service. It then does an
       execution pass executing CoreCompile passing SkipCompilerExecution=true and ProvideCommandLineArgs=true,
       that resulting command line string is where we get our compiler switches. The execution pass is much
       slower than the evaluation pass, so there's a window of time where we have a list of files, but not
       any options yet.

       Because there's a gap, that means there's a time where we are parsing source files with the default
       parse options. We'll then have to reparse them a second time which isn't great. It also means any
       cache lookups we do won't have the right options either, so the cache lookups might miss.

       To help this, we'll have properties for the evaluation pass which is an "approximation" of the
       options that would come out of CoreCompile, but only the ones that are required to be specified
       and we don't expect them to change after evaluation phase or those that matter for parsing.

       It's acceptable for the options that affect parsing to be imperfect: once the execution pass is complete we'll use those options instead,
       so any behaviors here that don't match the real command line generation will only be temporary, and
       probably won't be any worse than having no options at all. -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CommandLineArgsForDesignTimeEvaluation>-langversion:$(LangVersion)</CommandLineArgsForDesignTimeEvaluation>
    <CommandLineArgsForDesignTimeEvaluation Condition="'$(ChecksumAlgorithm)' != ''">$(CommandLineArgsForDesignTimeEvaluation) -checksumalgorithm:$(ChecksumAlgorithm)</CommandLineArgsForDesignTimeEvaluation>
    <CommandLineArgsForDesignTimeEvaluation Condition="'$(DefineConstants)' != ''">$(CommandLineArgsForDesignTimeEvaluation) -define:$(DefineConstants)</CommandLineArgsForDesignTimeEvaluation>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Anyone know what's going on? Thanks in advance!